# What are the differences in SBT Project and Scala Module in IntelliJ?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

Started learning Scala recently. I know the differences between `build.sbt` and `build.scala`. But what are the differences in between these two project types in [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scala Module in IDEA doesn't have anything to do with SBT's `Build.scala`. It's just an [IDEA module](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/module.html) which contains Scala (and may or may not use SBT). If you and any other developers only ever want to work with the project from IDEA (and are sure that you'll never change your mind), using a non-SBT Scala module may be good enough; I personally prefer SBT even for this case (it's nicer to keep in version control than IDEA's module files, dependency management is simpler, there are a lot of useful SBT plugins, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The differences 'in' IntelliJ are the same as they are outside of IntelliJ. The SBT plugin references those files in the same manner as SBT outside of IntelliJ does.

It's possible, if you're seeing a difference, there are project settings that are interfering, but 'out of the box' you shouldn't see this.

Comment: Is there any other advantage if using SBT apart from it being a build a tool?

Comment: @PritamBanerjee Any advantage to what? Using IntelliJ, or using SBT?

Comment: using sbt project.

Comment: The Simple Build Tool is useful for building projects, running tests, creating artifacts, etc. You'll probably need it eventually regardless of whether you use IntelliJ - in fact, when IntelliJ does these things with a project that has the SBT plugin, it uses the SBT build definition to do so. This helps translate projects between dev environments and to production environments.